# how to set the drawer using the menu function in the activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

I have to put a drawer layout for my app, hence I have finished the layout and functions in an activity.Now, I'm unable to use Fragments.How can I set the drawer using the menu function in the activity?Please help me.This is my main layout

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"`enter code here`
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@color/MediumSeaGreen"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/notification_settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:padding="@dimen/menu_icon_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytrip_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Notification"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytrip_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/notification_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this the layout what i have designed for drawer,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_home_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/menu_icon_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_home_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytrip_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_Trips_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/menu_icon_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_trips_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Trips"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytrip_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_notification_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/menu_icon_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_notification_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Notification"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytrip_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_Settings_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/menu_icon_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytrip_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_profile_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/menu_icon_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_profile_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytrip_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_friends_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:padding="@dimen/menu_icon_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_friends_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Friends"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytrip_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"`enter code here`
        android:background="@color/gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

while clicking the notification_settings imageview in the main layout i have to view the below designed layout for drawer function please help me

Comment: what do you expect to put in drawer ?

Comment: So, thanks for the reply, Its like menu while clicking the menu button the drawer as to be open and show the other activity title in that drawer .

Comment: something like this http://cdn1.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/android-navigation-drawer-sliding-menu.png?805852 ??

Comment: yes,but i cant use fragment class

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. replace your current activity layout with this,

   ```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



   <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/content_frame"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   // put your existing widgets here

   </FrameLayout>


   <ListView
   android:id="@+id/drawer_menu"
   android:layout_width="define your width"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   />
   ```
2. Instantiate drawer layout, your menu list, action bar and toggle  in your activity.
3. Define suitable row layout for the list and set the data. You can easily find sample code from here.

Comment: thanks for your codings ,please give me how to Instantiate drawer layout in my activity,i dont anything about this please help.

Comment: Try here, this is well explained http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: it doesn't matter, You just need to look at their main activity . Fragment or activity has nothing to do with instantiating action bar, toggle, drawer layout etc. Then once click on the menu , you just need to call the intent for relevant activity instead of calling fragment  :) just try

Comment: displayView method is used select the activity where the user wants to go,that mean i have to use intent for that cases ha

Comment: i have to put the list of string and icon in the same activity itself not to be in seprate string for that what i want to do

Comment: i have refered an example from this http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android  here it shows me one error in the setup drawer method android.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle does not support for(project name)

Comment: i have got the drawer from the above example which i have said but the problem is i am getting my drawer in the menu but i want the drawer to be in my layout

Comment: you can not have a drawer in your activity layout, If you need, you have to forget the navigation drawer and setup your menu as a list.

Comment: ok but i a designed a layout for drawer how i can set that layout for the drawer please help me this my big problem i had.

Comment: post it here plz ,  modify your question

Comment: i have modified my codings above please help me

Comment: OK, now you can try my above answer, instead of image/text , blocks, you can create a single custom view a each image/text and then add those to list view , try this , https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-android-listview-rows-subclassing/

Comment: i cant uder stand what your saying

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is, you need a layout that have several vertical linear layouts. In each vertical linear layout, you have a image and a textview. Like wise you have 4-5 vertical layouts. But the same thing can be achieved by creating a custom listview row layout. There you need only one row-view that has imageview and a text. It will create required 4-5 rows at run-time. The reason is, when you have lots of layouts it will cause
a performance issue. Using a listview row method is the recommended way.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply,but i will use listview for the drawer my questions is how i can show my drawer while clicking the notification_button setting in the above main activity,please help me